# How to Migrate vCenter Virtual Appliance

Tags: vmware-esxi, migration, vmware-vcenter

I am looking to migrate a vCenter 5.0 virtual appliance to another machine with DAS. Is it possible to do this without vMotion and without breaking anything?

If so, could one follow a similar process to migrating a VM without a vCenter server as outlined [here](http://www.virtualizetips.com/2010/04/how-to-move-a-vm-without-vcenter-or-storage-vmotion/)?

EDIT : This methodology worked well, however there was an issue with the machine detecting the NIC card after the migration. This was caused by the fact the MAC address of the NIC had changed. VMWare has this issue documented at the following site : http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2012451

Once the change was applied the system started up without issue.

Comment: Presumably you mean 'Live Migrate' right, as "just shut it down and move it" seems too easy for this answer but fits as it's written.

Comment: I am okay with shutting it down and moving it, however I don't know if that will break anything which is why I've asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, based on your comments then no, just shut it down, move the whole directory and re-add the VM, that's all you'll need to do.

Comment: While this is what I suspected I would rather ask a seemingly dumb question here than have egg on my face if things went awry